# Dependency Injection with multiple interface and partial class

Tags: .net-core, dependency-injection, .net-8.0

I have a class which is common for all my applications. Initially I was having different class and different class files for each functionality like DBContext, SendEmail, DataCache. It work fine if I register each of them separately. But these are common for more than 40 applications. Then I thought to have one single partial class and multiple interfaces. The reason to have one single class is to have one single registration of the interface

This is my common interface. Other interfaces will have their own methods

```
`public interface ICommon:IInterface1,IInterface2,Interface3
{
  public string M1();
  public string M2();
}`
```

```
public interface IInterface1
{
  public string M3();
}

public interface IInterface2
{
  public string M4();
}

public interface IInterface3
{
  public string M5();
}
```

In my single class file

```
public partial class common : ICommon
{
   public string M1()
   {
   }
   
   public string M2()
   {
   }
}
```

then extension of this partial class as need to add other methods too from rest of the interfaces(1,2,3)

```
public partial class : ICommon
{
  public string M3()
   {
   }
}
public partial class : ICommon
{
  public string M4()
  {
  }
}
public partial class : ICommon
{
  public string M5()
  {
  }
}
```

Then in my application, in program.cs file, I am registering the interface common

```
builder.Services.AddScoped<ICommon,Common>();
```

But I am getting error as  "System.AggregateException: 'Some services are not able to be constructed (Error while validating the service descriptor "

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: It sounds like you're putting lots of different functionality into one class. Just because they're `partial` doesn't mean they're separate classes. Having one class doing more than one "thing" will lead to your application becoming very hard to maintain, and you should definitely re-think this. Have a read of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID

Comment: @Andrew, so do you recommend registering them separately instead one single interface?

Comment: Could you give some real examples of the Interface names, to give us an idea of the domain? But yes, usually you'd have one Interface for each domain-specific purpose, which is the "single responsibility principle" of SOLID.

Comment: I guess the question to ask yourself is: why are you wanting to merge all the functionality into one class. Is it just to reduce the number of lines of code in your dependency injection? If so, consider whether that's a worthwhile trade-off against having a less maintainable codebase. If you think about it, you'd spend longer on future maintenance, than on putting another 30 lines of code in the DI config.

Comment: For example, ISendEmail, ICacheData, IDBContext.  I have around 40 different APIs. Do I need to register all the above mentioned separately. Can't I do it with one single registration. But my question is about to achieve the DI using one single Interface.

Comment: Ah! If you're just wanting to register the same "common" dependencies in each of those API projects, then a normal way to do this is define your own Extension Method (in a "Common" project) which does those particular bits of DI. You API projects can then all reference that Common project. I'll drop an Answer in now with an example...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to have a single line of DI config that sets up lots of your common DI, and use that across many API projects, then here's a suggestion.

Have a Project which is your Common dependencies. Something like `Api.CommonDependencies` if that helps. In there, define a static extension method like this:

```cs
public static class ServiceCollectionExtensionsForCommonApi
{
    public static IServiceCollection AddCommonApiDependencies(this IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddScoped<ISendEmail, MyEmailSender>();
        services.AddScoped<ICacheData, MyCacheImplementation>();
        services.AddScoped<IDBContext, MyDbContext();
        return services;
    }
}
```

And then in each of your 40 API projects, you can reference that `Api.CommonDependencies` project, and use them in your `Startup` or `Program.cs` (depending what type of API project they are).

e.g. if it were a .NET 8 Isolated Functions API project:

```cs
var host = new HostBuilder()
    .ConfigureFunctionsWorkerDefaults()
    .ConfigureServices(services =>
    {
        services
            .AddCommonApiDependencies() // your extension method
            .AddHttpClient() // or whatever else you need
//etc
    })
    .Build();

host.Run();
```

Comment: thank you for response, one quick question, in my controller how to access the AddCommonApiDependencies. For example if I need to use Cache in the controller, and that GetCache is in my main project. On top of main project I have the commonAPi Dependencies project.

Comment: Do I need to use my main project in the API Controller? And this AddCommonAPIDependencies is only for DI? THis is how I added "builder.Services.AddCommonApiDependencies();" in my program.cs

Comment: Your suggestion worked for me. My whole requirement is to have single point of reference for common project in the all the projects. In my common project, I will be having dbcontext, sendemail, datacache and security (this can grow as per requirement). For all these I don't want to use DI for each and every class(as I am maintaining each one of them in different classes).

Comment: Great! Pleased you found the approach useful.

Comment: I think I found the solution, I am using IServiceProvider in my controller and calling GetService method typeof(ICacheData) like  'var service = _serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(ICacheData)) as ICacheData;'

Comment: Hmm typically you would set up the Dependency Injection with a single call in your API Project setup, and then your Controller would have a Constructor like `public MyController(ICacheData cacheData)`